# order by after limiting number of rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
PACKAGE     DISTANCE
--------    --------
 Q1           5.0

 Q2           4.5

 Q3           0.5
```

I want to extract the rows in MySQL in such a way that Q2 is followed by Q1.

When I use this query

```
select package,distance from new_travel order by distance desc limit 0,2
```

I am getting Q1 followed by Q2.

When I use

```
 (select package,distance from new_travel order by distance desc limit 0,2) order by distance asc
```

its giving error. How to extract those rows in the order needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit in SQL means( in 0,2 for example)  start on 0 and bring two.  You need to bring three so do 0,3  on your limit.

Or, if you want to only bring the results Q2 and Q3  do  1,2

To get Q2 followed by Q1 all you need to do is:

```
select package,distance from new_travel order by distance asc limit 1,2
```

Comment: I am sorry, I want only Q1 and Q2 such that Q2 is followed by Q1

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks a lot Ryoku